# Python re.sub Substituting More Than Needed

Tags: python, regex

We have a 6 character strings that need to have the starting substring `"00"` replaced with "A".

Using the expression `^[0][0]*` on the first string `'001234'`, we get the expected result of `A1234`.

```
import re

# 1: Works fine
foo = '001234'
match = re.match(r"^[0][0][0-9]{4}$", foo)
print(match.group(0))       # 001234

bar = re.sub(r"^[0][0]*", 'A', match.group(0))
print(bar)                  # A1234
```

However, the second string `'000123'` was changed to `A123` instead of `A0123`.

```
# 2: Substitutes more than needed
foo = '000123'
match = re.match(r"^[0][0][0-9]{4}$", foo)
print(match.group(0))       # 000123

bar = re.sub(r"^[0][0]*", 'A', match.group(0))
print(bar)                  # A123
                            # Expects: A0123
```

What went wrong with the regex pattern, and how can we fix it?

Comment: Are you mistaking regexes for globs? `*` says the previous character (or group) repeats 0 or more times, it doesn't mean "allow anything here" like it does in globs. So `^[0][0]*` says to look for something that starts with at least one `0` and match all the leading zeroes (a shorter spelling would be `^0+`).

Comment: If you just have one character, e.g. `0` you can just write it as `0` in a regex instead of using character classes, i.e. `[0]` for simplicity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the number of zeros at the beginning of the line that you need to be replace,

```
foo = '000100'
re.sub(r'^0{2}', r'A', foo)

'A0100'
```

Comment: Why is `r'A'` used instead of `'A'`?

Comment: @AthenaWisdom: It doesn't matter in this case, but it's safest to use raw strings for both regex patterns and substitutions, so backslashes aren't inadvertently ignored or misinterpreted. When there are no backslashes, it's unnecessary, but it builds good habits.